# what is history id in user profile gmail api?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

got this output what does historyId mean and is it epoch time ?

```
UserInfo is 
 {'emailAddress': 'sssss@gmail.com', 'messagesTotal': 22919, 'threadsTotal': 22016, 'historyId': '1727906'}
```

code used

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'


userInfo = service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()
print ("UserInfo is \n %s" % (userInfo))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anwser: HistoryID is not epoc time its an id.

**Definition of history ID**

Directly from the doucmentation [getprofile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

> historyId  unsigned long   The **ID** of the mailbox's current history record.

**Usage**

used with [history.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)

> Lists the history of all changes to the given mailbox. History results are returned in chronological order (increasing historyId).

Also used in the following

**Synchronizing Clients with Gmail**

Keeping your client synchronized with Gmail is important for most application scenarios. There are two overall synchronization scenarios: full synchronization and partial synchronization. Full synchronization is required the first time your client connects to Gmail and in some other rare scenarios. If your client has recently synchronized, partial synchronization is a lighter-weight alternative to a full sync. You can also use push notifications to trigger partial synchronization in real-time and only when necessary, thereby avoiding needless polling.

You may also find [sync](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync)