# What increments a historyId in gmail api?

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Situation :
We are trying to sync messages from gmail of a account to our application using Gmail API.To do so, we can either poll the gmail api server and get the latest updates or we can use push notifications by google to notify us using pub/sub whenever there is a change in gmail state.

[push-notification-doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

Problem :
In case of push notification, google returns following payload.

`{"emailAddress":"****.raj@***.in","historyId":1439830}`

**the problem is** , it is not clear whether `historyId` represents single change in gmail ( eg messageAdded, LabelAdded etc etc.) or it is collection of similar event changes for eg if there is 5  replies on same email within 30 seconds, or 1 minutes or so, it will clubb together that change and constitute it in one historyId.

We tried sending replies on some email within 1 minute and changed label within certain time period.However we could not find any regular pattern while recieving historyId from gmail api server.

Answer (score 1):

HistoryID increments with changes in mail box, But I believe your inquiry is best answered with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list#query-parameters):

> History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between valid IDs

History ID is used with history list method as seen here in the [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list).

A good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54781429/19378826).